# How to highlight a Marker when hovering over it in plotly?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I'm trying to do something I thought would be easy, but I cannot figure it out. I have a very simple scatter plot below. I want the markers to get larger as I hover over them. For example, when my cursor is hovering over the point 3,3 in the chart (see image), I want the marker size to increase. Then, once I'm done hovering, I want the marker size to go back to its original size. I've created a simple scatter plot to get the code working but I can't even get it to work with this. Please see code and image below.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Create a line chart with random data
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
fig = go.Figure()
scatter = go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, mode='lines+markers')
fig.add_trace(scatter)

fig.write_html('test.html', auto_open=True)
```

[Scatter Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cU3po.png)

Comment: as far as i know, this kind of feature isn't possible in `plotly-python`. you could probably achieve this in `plotly-dash` because `callbacks` are supported and you could pass information about which data point you have hovered over back to your program, and modify the marker size accordingly. if you're interested in a plotly-dash based solution, i could write up something like that for you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.